# Django, model instance attribute which is not a field?

Tags: django, model

I'd like to have an attribute which doesn't persist in DB.

For example, I would read a list of objects from DB and assign a score to each of them to sort on it.

How should I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the attribute of an object any time your want:

```
import random

objects = []
for obj in MyModel.objects.all():
    obj.score = random.randint(0, 100)
    objects.append(obj)

sorted_objects = sorted(objects, key=lambda x: x.score)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
sorted_objects = sorted(map(lambda x: x.score = random.randint(0,100),MyModel.objects.all()),key = lambda x:x.score)
```